# How come random weight initiation is better then just using 0 as weights in ANN?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

In a trained neural net the weight distribution will fall close around zero. So it makes sense for me to initiate all weights to zero. However there are methods such as random assignment for -1 to 1 and Nguyen-Widrow that outperformes zero initiation. How come these random methods are better then just using zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Activation & learning:**

Additionally to the things cr0ss said, in a normal MLP (for example) the activation of layer n+1 is the dot product of the output of layer n and the weights between layer n and n + 1...so basically you get this equation for the activation **a** of neuron **i** in layer **n**:

[image]

Where w is the weight of the connection between neuron j (parent layer n-1) to current neuron i (current layer n), o is the output of neuron j (parent layer) and b is the bias of current neuron i in the current layer.

It is easy to see initializing weights with zero would practically "deactivate" the weights because weights by output of parent layer would equal zero, therefore (in the first learning steps) your input data would **not** be recognized, the data would be negclected totally.
So the learning would **only** have the data supplied by the bias in the first epochs.

This would obviously render the learning more challenging for the network and enlarge the needed epochs to learn heavily.

**Initialization should be optimized for your problem:**

Initializing your weights with a distribution of random floats with -1 <= w <= 1 is the most typical initialization, because overall (if you do not analyze your problem / domain you are working on) this guarantees some weights to be relatively good right from the start. Besides, other neurons co-adapting to each other happens faster with fixed initialization and random initialization ensures better learning.

However -1 <= w <= 1 for initialization is not optimal for every problem. For example: biological neural networks do not have negative outputs, so weights should be positive when you try to imitate biological networks. Furthermore, e.g. in image processing, most neurons have either a fairly high output or send nearly nothing. Considering this, it is often a good idea to initialize weights between something like 0.2 <= w <= 1, sometimes even 0.5 <= w <= 2 showed good results (e.g. in dark images).

So the needed epochs to learn a problem properly is not only dependent on the layers, their connectivity, the transfer functions and learning rules and so on but also to the initialization of your weights.
You should try several configurations. In most situations you can figure out what solutions are adequate (like higher, positive weights for processing dark images).

Comment: great explanation, well put! +1

Comment: I think most confusion and "mystification" in artificial intelligence domains only exist because of too specific or too few information in combination with not very illustrative descriptions. Thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Nguyen article, I'd say it is because when you assign the weight from -1 to 1, you are already defining a "direction" for the weight, and it will learn if the direction is correct and it's magnitude to go or not the other way.

If you assign all the weights to zero (in a MLP neural network), you don't know which direction it might go to. Zero is a `neutral` number.

Therefore, if you assign a small value to the node's weight, the network will learn faster.

Read [`Picking initial weights to speed training`](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee373b/nninitialization.pdf) section of the article. It states:

> First, the elements of Wi are assigned values from a uniform random distributation between -1 and 1 so that its direction is random. Next, we adjust the magnitude of the weight vectors Wi, so that each hidden node is linear over only a small interval.

Hope it helps.